Estimating markov transition matrix using total elevator "ups" and "downs" by floor
I have data on elevator presses and I am hoping to use them to estimate a Markov transition matrix, so I can ultimately estimate how frequently people go to different floors.
For each floor from 1-4, I have the # of UP presses and the # of DOWN presses. For instance, let's say 50% of UP presses originate from floor 1, 30% of UP from floor 2, and the remaining 20% UP from floor 3 (necessarily bound for floor 4). Let's say we also know the DOWNs, with 50% from floor 4, 40% from floor 3, and the remaining 10% from floor 2.
Fl Ups Downs
 1  50     0
 2  30    10
 3  20    40
 4   0    50

I will assume that no one ever uses the stairs, which means the total rides TO each floor need to match the rides FROM each floor.
Is that enough data to make a reasonable estimate of the transition matrix or would we need to make other simplifying assumptions?

Playing around with this example, I sketched out a matrix corresponding to my example numbers. The rows in the green region of the matrix need to add up to the the green Ups on the right, and the rows in the orange region need to add to the orange Downs on the right.
If I assume no one uses any stairs, then if 50 people ride from FL1, then 50 people need to ride to FL1 as well, so I need the columns to match the totals at the bottom.
It looks like each region has one degree of flexibility, where specifying any one of the numbers in gray will determine all the other numbers in gray in that region.
Perhaps this ends up being a question of domain knowledge, but I wonder if there are any standard assumptions that might point to some solutions of the matrix being more likely than others. I want the destination mix from each floor to be as similar to the destination mix from other floors as possible, reflecting some innate attractiveness of each floor that is irrespective of the source floor.


You need more assumptions. If you consider the 30 ups from floor 2, they might all go to floor 3 or all go to floor 4 or have some mixture of the two.  Similarly with some of the other choices.  So you need further assumptions for that.   There is a coincidence of up and down presses (this might lead you to assume nobody uses the stairs in one direction only), and you might also want to assume that presses have similar sharing patterns up and down (which is not what I would have guessed before seeing the numbers).
